# Sorting,Filtering and Pagination in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

I am new to mean stack and for the first time writing code in AngularJS, I am trying to implement Sorting, Paging and Filtering in below index.html file. Something isn't right how I am trying to implement, please help
Here is my index.html file -

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

  <title>eAPI Test Execution Portal</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <h1>eAPI Test Execution Portal</h1>

    <table class="table table-fluid">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><a href="" ng-click="orderByField='runId'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">runId</a>
            <th><a href="" ng-click="orderByField='apiName'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">apiName</a>
            </th>
          </th>
          <th><a href="" ng-click="orderByField='runTime'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">runTime</a>
          </th>
          <th><a href="" ng-click="orderByField='Report'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">Report</a>
          </th>
          <th><a href="" ng-click="orderByField='numOfTestExecuted'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">numOfTestExecuted</a>
          </th>
          <th><a href="" ng-click="orderByField='numOfTestFailed'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">numOfTestFailed</a>
          </th>
          <th><a href="" ng-click="orderByField='status'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">status</a>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="search.runId" placeholder="Search by runId" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="search.apiName" placeholder="Search by apiName" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="search.runTime" placeholder="Search by runTime" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="url" ng-model="search.Report" placeholder="Search by Report URL" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="search.numOfTestExecuted" placeholder="Search by numOfTestExecuted" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="search.numOfTestFailed" placeholder="Search by numOfTestFailed" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" ng-model="search.status" placeholder="Search by status" />
          </td>

        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="contact in contactlist">
          <td>{{contact.runId}}</td>
          <td>{{contact.apiName}}</td>
          <td>{{contact.runTime}}</td>
          <td>{{contact.Report}}</td>
          <td>{{contact.numOfTestExecuted}}</td>
          <td>{{contact.numOfTestFailed}}</td>
          <td>{{contact.status}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="contact in contactlist | orderBy:predicate:reverse | filter:paginate| filter:search" ng-class-odd="'odd'">
          <td>{{user.runId}}</td>
          <td>{{user.apiName}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" max-size="5" boundary-links="true" items-per-page="numPerPage" class="pagination-sm">
    </pagination>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.12/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="controllers/controller.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the controller.js file - (If you want to try in your local, using mean stack)

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {
    console.log("Hello World from controller");


    var refresh = function() {
      $http.get('/contactlist').success(function(response) {
        console.log("I got the data I requested");
        $scope.contactlist = response;
        $scope.contact = "";
      });
    };

    refresh();

    $scope.addContact = function() {
      console.log($scope.contact);
      $http.post('/contactlist', $scope.contact).success(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        refresh();
      });
    };

    $scope.remove = function(id) {
      console.log(id);
      $http.delete('/contactlist/' + id).success(function(response) {
        refresh();
      });
    };

    $scope.edit = function(id) {
      console.log(id);
      $http.get('/contactlist/' + id).success(function(response) {
        $scope.contact = response;
      });
    };

    $scope.update = function() {
      console.log($scope.contact._id);
      $http.put('/contactlist/' + $scope.contact._id, $scope.contact).success(function(response) {
        refresh();
      })
    };

    $scope.deselect = function() {
      $scope.contact = "";
    }

  }
]);
```

You may use this to insert data in your local Mongo -

```
db.contactlist.insert({"runId" : "1212","apiName" :     "transactions","runTime" : "DateAndTime","Report" : "URL","numOfTestExecuted" : "3","numOfTestFailed" : "3","status" : "Passed"})
```

Comment: Tip: You are using a directive for Pagination, you should also create a directive for your Sorting.

Comment: @squadwuschel - Thanks for the tip, will appreciate if you could update the code. As I mentioned, I am new to Angular and learning as I go by actual coding. Wish I had time to take classes or a course

Answer (score 0):

It would be cool, if you can tell me whats not working in your example, perhaps it would be better to drill down your problems a bit into three issues:

Sorting, Paging and Filtering.

Create a example for each of it and try to implement it and then ask the direct question what is not working.

-> because each of the problems could be solved independently and then its easier for you to understand how the hole thing works together.

you could create a stand alone directive for each of your Problems.

Comment: Thanks for the direction - Problem 1 - <input type="text" ng-model="search.runId" placeholder="Search by runId" /> With this I expect that when I type something in the text box it will find all the matching runId's as I am typing. Problem 2 - With this '<th><a href="" ng-click="orderByField='runId'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">runId</a>' I was hoping to sort to happen upon click.

Comment: your first Problem is, that you have two ng-repeat in your table - I don't understand why. But first create a new testproject where you can test every single feature until it works like you want and when you have a problem, then create for every problem a new StackOverflow post.